# Total hours of Brexit negotiations?

Tags: brexit, statistics, data-sources

Brexit negotiations are important, as there is much to lose on both sides. But I am wondering:

How many hours were spent since the referendum on negotiation talks?

Is it possible to estimate? I could not find any news articles mentioning it, and it is also not on Wikipedia, and I also couldn't find, for example, a report listing all the meetings of Michel Barnier with durations.

Comment: I find it unlikely to ever get a number, considering the difficulty of defining negotiations. These days, would it count if Johnson phones Merkel or wouldn't it (because the EU27 said they wouldn't talk about Brexit bilaterally)?

Comment: One could find a upper limit with an inclusive definition and a lower limit with a more stringent definition.

Comment: How do you define negotiation talks? Does it only count the official meetings? Or are you also including unofficial meetings and converstations?

Comment: @JoeW: Any number - if it comes with its definition - will be interesting.

Comment: That is a very broad question and can attract many conflicting answers.

Answer (score 2):

I found all the negotiation meeting agendas by the [UK](https://www.gov.uk/search/all?keywords=future%20relationship%20negotiations&order=relevance) and EU ([1](https://ec.europa.eu/commission/brexit-negotiations_en), [2](https://ec.europa.eu/info/european-union-and-united-kingdom-forging-new-partnership_en)). From there, the meeting dates are listed in the table below.

These are 115 days.

Most meetings are weeks with a half-day (2.5h) each in the beginning and end, and 2-3 days of full-day (7h) meetings in between ([example](https://ec.europa.eu/info/sites/info/files/agenda_of_eu-uk_negotiations_-_20-24_april_2020.pdf)), often with 4-9 parallel sessions. Taking a very rough average here of ((6 parallel sessions) * (7h) * (2 days) + (2.5h * 2 days)) / (4 days) gives 22.25 hours of talks per day. I chose 2 days here, because there are also some single day meetings and telecons, some half-day, some full-day, so it accounts for these more or less. The number is high because of the parallel talks.

Multiplying the two together, gives a total of **2559 hours**.

Missing are inofficial meetings, talks on summits, phone calls, etc.. Naturally there are caveats in the above calculation.

Table of meetings:

| Year | Month | Day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | 6 | 19 |
|  | 7 | 17 |
|  |  | 18 |
|  |  | 19 |
|  |  | 20 |
|  | 8 | 28 |
|  |  | 29 |
|  |  | 30 |
|  |  | 31 |
|  | 9 | 25 |
|  |  | 26 |
|  |  | 27 |
|  |  | 28 |
|  | 10 | 9 |
|  |  | 10 |
|  |  | 11 |
|  |  | 12 |
|  | 11 | 9 |
|  |  | 10 |
| 2018 | 1 | 16 |
|  |  | 17 |
|  |  | 29 |
|  | 2 | 6 |
|  |  | 7 |
|  |  | 8 |
|  |  | 9 |
|  |  | 19 |
|  |  | 20 |
|  |  | 26 |
|  |  | 27 |
|  | 3 | 5 |
|  |  | 6 |
|  |  | 7 |
|  |  | 13 |
|  |  | 14 |
|  |  | 15 |
|  |  | 16 |
|  |  | 17 |
|  |  | 18 |
|  |  | 19 |
|  | 4 | 16 |
|  |  | 17 |
|  |  | 18 |
|  | 5 | 22 |
|  |  | 23 |
|  |  | 24 |
|  | 6 | 5 |
|  |  | 6 |
|  |  | 7 |
|  |  | 8 |
|  |  | 19 |
|  |  | 20 |
|  | 7 | 16 |
|  |  | 17 |
|  |  | 18 |
|  |  | 19 |
|  |  | 24 |
|  |  | 25 |
|  |  | 26 |
|  | 8 | 16 |
|  |  | 17 |
|  |  | 21 |
|  |  | 22 |
|  |  | 29 |
|  |  | 30 |
|  |  | 31 |
|  | 9 | 5 |
|  |  | 6 |
| 2019 | 2 | 7 |
|  | 3 | 11 |
|  | 4 | 10 |
| 2020 | 3 | 2 |
|  |  | 3 |
|  |  | 4 |
|  |  | 5 |
|  |  | 30 |
|  | 4 | 15 |
|  |  | 20 |
|  |  | 21 |
|  |  | 22 |
|  |  | 23 |
|  |  | 24 |
|  | 5 | 11 |
|  |  | 12 |
|  |  | 13 |
|  |  | 14 |
|  |  | 15 |
|  | 6 | 2 |
|  |  | 3 |
|  |  | 4 |
|  |  | 5 |
|  |  | 12 |
|  |  | 29 |
|  |  | 30 |
|  | 7 | 1 |
|  |  | 2 |
|  |  | 3 |
|  |  | 20 |
|  |  | 21 |
|  |  | 22 |
|  |  | 23 |
|  | 8 | 18 |
|  |  | 19 |
|  |  | 20 |
|  |  | 21 |
|  | 9 | 8 |
|  |  | 9 |
|  |  | 10 |
|  |  | 28 |
|  |  | 29 |
|  |  | 30 |
|  | 10 | 1 |
|  |  | 2 |
|  |  | 9 |
|  |  | 19 |